# creating a shopping list with a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Okay so I have my json file:

```
[
 {"task":"get milk","who":"Scott","dueDate":"2013-05-19","done":false},
 {"task":"get broccoli","who":"Elisabeth","dueDate":"2013-05-21","done":false},
 {"task":"get garlic","who":"Trish","dueDate":"2013-05-30","done":false},
 {"task":"get eggs","who":"Josh","dueDate":"2013-05-15","done":true}
]
```

and my html/jquery file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To do List</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script> 
            $("document").ready(function() {
                $.getJSON("todo.json", function(data) {
                    console.log("Data loaded successfully");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="list">
            <ul class="list-items">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is grab each json array and create a to-do list with it; however, I am having dificulties displaying the arrays so I could then add them to a list item

Comment: Won't `1 < data.length` loop forever?

Comment: What difficulties are you facing? Parsing a JSON is pretty straight forward - what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @GautamBhutani I want to grab each array and place it in a<li> displaying each of them as a list item of my to-do list

Comment: google for javascript `for`-loops and jQuery `append`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here is more or less the same with jQuery

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-items">
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var data = [
 {"task":"get milk","who":"Scott","dueDate":"2013-05-19","done":false},
 {"task":"get broccoli","who":"Elisabeth","dueDate":"2013-05-21","done":false},
 {"task":"get garlic","who":"Trish","dueDate":"2013-05-30","done":false},
 {"task":"get eggs","who":"Josh","dueDate":"2013-05-15","done":true}
];

var ul = $('.list-items');
$.each(data, function(i, elem) {
    var text = 'Task: ' + elem.task + ', Name: ' + elem.who + ', Date: ' + elem.dueDate;
    ul.append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9vEj/)

Comment: Thanks this looks much cleaner but if i try to display all of the elements using '<li>' + elem.task elem.who elem.dueDate + '</li>' it doesnt display anythng

Comment: jQuery looks cleaner and would get the job done faster; however, I'm not too fond of appending 'string' as elements. Personally, I prefer creating elements and then sticking in the string I require.

Comment: @swsa You put the parts together with `+`. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/x4vuB/1/

HTML

```
<div>
<ul id="myList">
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myJSON = [
 {"task":"get milk","who":"Scott","dueDate":"2013-05-19","done":false},
 {"task":"get broccoli","who":"Elisabeth","dueDate":"2013-05-21","done":false},
 {"task":"get garlic","who":"Trish","dueDate":"2013-05-30","done":false},
 {"task":"get eggs","who":"Josh","dueDate":"2013-05-15","done":true}
] 
var myList=document.getElementById('myList');
for(var counter = 0; counter < myJSON.length; counter++) {
 var myListItem = document.createElement('li');
 var myListElement = document.createElement('div');
    myListElement.innerHTML = "Name: "+myJSON[counter].who;
    myListElement.innerHTML += "<br/>"+"Task: "+myJSON[counter].task;
    myListElement.innerHTML += "<br/>"+"Date: "+myJSON[counter].dueDate;
    myListElement.innerHTML += "<br/>"+"Done: "+myJSON[counter].done;
    myListItem.appendChild(myListElement);
    myList.appendChild(myListItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var the_list = data[i];
    for(l_item in the_list){
        if(the_list.hasOwnProperty(l_item)){
            your_html_here.innerHTML = l_item +":"+ the_list[l_item];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (is that extra `}` supposed to be there?)